# Extend meta query arguments

Tags: meta-query

I have this meta query:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'fl_type',
            'value' => 'Awards'
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'fl_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
```

However I need to extend this by another 2 numeric variables `fl_expire = 0` and `fl_global = 1` and I can't figure out the correct syntax for this.

Comment: Can you format your code with newlines and indentation? It's all written on a single line making it extremely difficult to read

Comment: Ok I have done this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'fl_type',
            'value' => 'Awards'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'fl_expire',
            'value' => 0,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'fl_global',
            'value' => 1,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'fl_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
```